# Changing Highcharter Color Palette without storing the colour scheme as an object

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I would like to change the color palette highcharter uses to one of the viridis options. Usually, I simply pull out virids colors for each unique observation in the target column:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(highcharter)

df = tibble(id = c(1:20),
            name = c(sample(c('name1','name2','name3','name4'), 20, replace = TRUE)),
            value = round(runif(20, min = 10, max = 15),0))

colors = scales::viridis_pal(option = 'turbo', begin = 0.45, direction = -1)(length(unique(df$name)))


df %>% 
  hchart("spline", hcaes(x = id, y = value, group = name)) %>% 
  hc_colors(colors)
```

[image]

I was wondering if it was possible to achieve the same result without storing potential changes. Suppose that I want to only display 'name1' and 'name2' through a filter, but I don't want to store that subset as an object in the environment:

```
df %>% 
  filter(name %in% c('name1','name2')) %>% 
  hchart("spline", hcaes(x = id, y = value, group = name)) %>% 
  hc_colors(colors)
```

[image]

Instead of calling a stored colour vector, which doesn't automatially re-adjust with less variables, I would like to have an automatically defined scale (like ggplot's scale_colour function) or be able to get the colours from a column. That way I could use `mutate` and `colorize` and pipe the result in.

Comment: I am sorry, but could please explain again what you exactly want? Do you want to combine all code to have pipe?

Comment: I'll try to rephrase a bit by editing my original question. In ggplot, the colour scale is automatically adjusted to fit the number of variables present (if discrete). With Highcharter you have to create a colour vector prior to generating the code for the chart. I was wondering if there was a way you could pipe the colour scheme instead of storing it in an object.

Comment: You could define your colors using hc_theme. See: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/highcharter/versions/0.8.2/topics/hc_theme